# web request not working on app first run

Tags: android

I have web request helper class in my app using `OKHttp3` via standard async method call. everything just work fine, but in my Splash Activity just for first run (after new installation) web request calling not work! but if I close the app and run again everything work fine.

here is my call back interface:

```
public interface WebResult<T> {
void onValue(T value);}
```

here is calling method

```
 public void getStatus(final WebResult result) {
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("action", "test");
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("reqbody", cd.toJSON());

    String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", AuthKey)
            .url(url)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            setHasError(true);
            setMsg(e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {

                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            } else {
                iAct.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            String s = response.body().string();
                            ServerStat r = new ServerStat();
                            r.fromJSON(s);

                            result.onValue(r);
                            return;
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and its my splash activity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = this;

     WebHelper wh = new WebHelper(context);
    wh.getStatus(new WebResult() {
        @Override
        public void onValue(Object value) {
            ServerStat r = (ServerStat) value;
            if (r.getErrorCode() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, r.getErrorMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, r.getErrorMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: share your code?

Comment: here is my code

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced OKHttp3 with google Volley and it's work in my case!